# Accessing php files inside our own created folder in htdocs

Tags: php, xampp

I am new to PHP. I am creating a website using macromedia dreamweaver. I am saving my php files in `C:/Xampp/htdocs/myFolder`. myFolder is folder created by me inside `htdocs`. I want to access php files inside myFolder but i am getting an error 404. If I copied my PHP files inside `htdocs` then i am able to access it. Can I access PHP files that are saved in myFolder?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your website will not be visible to your browser if you just put it in your `C:/Xampp/htdocs/myFolder` without turning on the XAMPP services. You must start the Apache services and MySQL services via XAMPP's conrol panel in order for your localhost to work properly.

Second thing is you must have a `.php` file named `index.php` inside your `myFolder` folder. `index.php` is the first file that the browser will crawl upon visiting your website. However, you can still browse your file by providing the exact file name in the `url` of the website you are trying to view. For example, instead of `index.php` you have in there something like `example.php`, you can then type the `url` to your browser as `localhost/myFolder/example.php` and in that case, the content of the `example.php` will be the one that the browser will read and display its content.

Comment: I have started all the services but i forgot to mention here.Actually myFolder contains different PHP files which are interconnected.For eg- I have a registration button on my home screen.If I click on registration link from home screen then it access the registration file that is outside myFolder but if I save this file inside myFolder then i am getting Error 404.

Comment: @AnushkaAgarwal -- You are getting a 404 error code because the path of your registration button is targeting the `registration` file located outside of your `myFolder` folder and it is not there anymore because you have moved it inside your `myFolder` folder. If you moved your `registration` file inside your `myFolder` folder, then you should also changed the target `url` of your `registration button` to the exact new path of your `registration` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

localhost/myFolder/blabla.php

Comment: @witherwind-I am accessing files in this way only bt getting error

Comment: It's 404? Can you post your folder directory here?

Comment: @witherwind-yeah sure. folder directory is C:/xampp/htdocs/Survey.In Survey folder I hv different php files.

Comment: What's the error you are seeing? Or have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: @witherwind-error is'Object not found' Requested site is not found on the server. i have not tried the IP address. I am accessing it using local host.

Comment: What's the URL that you are using? Try replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1", it does the same.

Comment: @witherwind-ok i will try it but i dont think its gonna work because local host and its ip address is same thing

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how many folders you have inside your subfolder.Xampp by default will allow you to create your own folder within htdocs.but you can only create a maximum of two folders inside that subfolder by default.Create a new subfolder,then make sure that subfolder thats inside htdocs,only has a maximum of 2 folders with your php files and all.It worked for me.My Xampp was failing to find or even display the 3rd folder inside my subfolder.

i.e localhost/newfolder/projectfolder/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi just found a solution, try not using capital letters on the folder's name. Good Luck!